# WPF: Accessing databound data in code behind each time the binding source is updated?

Tags: wpf, listbox, data-binding

Is there a way to get code behind access to databound data each time it updates? I have seen the static ValidateValueCallback delegate that can be hooked into a DependencyProperty, but that's static and really, it's purpose is just for validation.

I have a number of situations where I need to update other objects as a databound source is updated. One example is an animated ListBox where I need to add an animation to just the first new item added to the box. I therefore need access to the newly updated binding source items so that I can work out which items are new and which items should be animated out of the Listbox.

To be clear, I have a UserControl with a DependencyProperty that a data source is bound to externally and a ListBox.ItemSource is bound to internally.

I'm thinking there must be an easy way to achieve this, but after several days of searching, I still haven't found any examples.

In response to DJacobson's reply, here is some example code:

Inside the UserControl we have a ListBox:

```
    <ListBox Name="TheAnimatedListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding QueueItems, ElementName=UserControlName}" 
ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource QueueItemStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
MouseDown="QueueItemsListBox_MouseDown" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="300">
```

The UserControl has no DataContext set and is declared like this:

```
<Controls:AnimatedQueue Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="FirstResponseQueue"
QueueItems="{Binding FirstResponseItems}" />
```

QueueItems is a DependencyProperty declared in the UserControl of type AnimatableObservableCollection object. AnimatableObservableCollection extends ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that if I use a UIPropertyMetadata object instead of a FrameworkPropertyMetadata object in the DependencyProperty declaration, then I can attach a PropertyChangedCallback handler which is called each time the DependencyProperty is updated. It is used as follows:

```
public readonly static DependencyProperty AnimatableItemsProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("AnimatableItems", typeof(ItemCollection), typeof
(YourClassNameHere), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnAnimatableItemsChanged));

private static void OnAnimatableItemsChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((YourClassNameHere)dependencyObject).CallAMethodOrPropertyHere(e);
}

public ItemCollection AnimatableItems
{
    get { return (ItemCollection)GetValue(AnimatableItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AnimatableItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

As the callback handler is static, you have to cast your control (the dependencyObject) to the type of your control/class and then you can call any non static members in your class. If your callback handler code is just one operation (eg. a method call or an assignment, etc.), then you can do without the handler altogether and use a lambda expression instead. This would be as follows:

```
public readonly static DependencyProperty AnimatableItemsProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("AnimatableItems", typeof(ItemCollection), typeof
(YourClassNameHere), new UIPropertyMetadata(
(d,e) => ((YourClassNameHere)d).CallAMethodOrPropertyHere(e)));
```

One last thing to note is that if you want to provide a default value, there are overloads of the UIPropertyMetadata constructor and one allows you to provide the default value, followed by a PropertyChangedCallback handler. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> To be clear, I have a UserControl with
>   a DependencyProperty that a data
>   source is bound to externally and a
>   ListBox.ItemSource is bound to
>   internally.

Does this mean the UserControl's `DataContext` is the data source, and the ListBox *within* the UserControl is then bound to the data source? Because that would make sense. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean - would you edit the question and share some of your code / XAML so it's a little more obvious what you're working with?

Assuming the scenario I outlined, for now, an `ObservableCollection` sounds like the way to go, and I've actually been able to animate additions to (and presumably removals from) an ItemsControl in XAML alone, without writing event handlers.

Let's say you bind the `ItemsSource` of your ListBox to an `ObservableCollection<YourListItemDataObjects>`. You can create a `DataTemplate` like the following and assign it to the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` property:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Name="animatedTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}">
        <TextBlock.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint>0.5,0.0</LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint>
                <LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint>0.5,1.0</LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="cellBackgroundBottomStopColor" 
                              Color="Orange" Offset="0.9"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Background>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="animatedTextBlock" 
                          RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="flashNewCell">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="cellBackgroundBottomStopColor" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                                        From="White" To="Orange" 
                                        Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="animatedTextBlock" 
                          RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseUp">
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="flashNewCell" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

You'll see that the `DataTemplate` will cause the ListItems to render as TextBoxes bound to the `Name` property of the objects in your `ObservableCollection` (change that property to whatever's appropriate in your case, obviously).

The complex bit is the animation. Notice the `EventTrigger`, whose `RoutedEvent` property is **"TextBlock.Loaded"**. That event will fire whenever an item is added to the `ObservableCollection` bound to the ListBox, since that causes a new ListBoxItem to be created - and thus a new TextBlock, whose `Loaded` event will fire.

Similarly, there is an Unloaded event you could trigger on when removing an item.

Also note that the `Storyboard.TargetName` property of the `ColorAnimation` refers to the name we gave the second `GradientStop` making up the TextBlock's background. This tells the animation which element in the TextBlock's visual tree to alter - typical WPF animations are always applied to the dependency properties of visual elements.

Applying an [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) on an EventTrigger allows you to apply effects (gradient colors, in this case, but you could play with Opacity to make fade-ins and fade-outs, as well) to a control when its bound datasource is altered.

The second `EventTrigger` in the example is activated on the `MouseUp` event that will occur when the user clicks on this TextBlock, and it removes the animation that we applied when the TextBlock was Loaded (notice the `AutoReverse="False"` setting on that first animation, which causes it to maintain its ending state until we explicitly remove it).

We now have a ListBox whose items "glow" for a few seconds when they are added, and which maintain a highlighted colour until we click on them.

Obviously, this is just a starting point - DataTemplates and Animations are both deep topics you may want to research further. But I hope you find this a helpful example of WPF's powerful binding capabilities and their potential to let you define your UI through XAML alone.

Comment: First, thank you for your very detailed response. However, I have the same code arrangement as you described and that much works fine. Well, I found that if I had an animation triggered by the ListBoxItem.Unloaded event that I would never see it because the item would disappear as soon as it was unloaded.

Comment: I therefore have to add an animation to it before it gets unloaded in code behind. Also in code, I need to compare the new items with the old ones and perform 'exit slide' animations on the items in the old collection but not the new and 'enter slide' animations on the new items. That's why I need access in code behind as the items are updated.

Comment: One other thing - when I set the UserControl's DataContext property to 'this', the items don't appear at all. So the only way that I could get it to work was by using ElementName="UserControlName" on each binding.

Comment: @Sheridan Good elaboration - you may wish to incorporate it back into the original question. I'm still holding out hope that there's a way to do these animations without attacking the visual tree through code (though if someone else wants to present such a solution, be my guest). To that end, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269248/wpf-how-to-animate-a-list-of-components) or [this demo code](http://adammills.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/visualstatemanager-execute-after-transition-finished/) *might* be useful...

Comment: Thanks again. I've just had a quick look at your links and the idea of having the animations in a custom panel inside the listbox sound interesting. I don't have time to get into it now, but I'll certainly have a good look when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

If your binding is two way then your underlying datasource object should be changing in sync with the front end. You could capture any changes to this object by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on it and attaching handlers to the event. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: If it's one-way from source, this technique still applies for updating the UI from the underlying data source.

Comment: My data type does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but the problem is not a 'UI not updating' problem, it's a 'not able to react to the changes in the bound data source from code behind' problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different approach to recognizing when a new item is added to the ListBox. Instead of trying to react to the UI telling you that data has changed, listen to changes on the data itself.

For example, if you ListBox is bound to an ObservableCollection then listen to the collection's CollectionChanged event to notify you that an item has been added.

```
    private void TestObservableCollection()
    {
        // Create you Collection and handle the CollectionChanged event so that 
        // you know when items are being added or removed from the collection.
        ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        people.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(people_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void people_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if a new item was added to the ObservableCollection<Person>
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            // Do something in the UI here....
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried exactly that, but program execution never enters the event handling method... I'm not sure why not.

Comment: Exactly that... except that I have an AnimatedObservableCollection<T> that I extended from ObservableCollection<T>, but I can't see why that would make any difference.