# can we slide listbox row in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to slide a selected listbox row, so that I can perform some operations over it. It can be implemented in Android but any luck with Windows Phone 7 ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope thie following link might be useful for you!!
Animating a list of components:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269248/wpf-how-to-animate-a-list-of-components/2269277#2269277

Comment: will go through it and let you know. Thanks.